# How to run maven using npm / yarn?

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, yarnpkg

I am currently trying to run maven using npm / yarn and saw that people already published packages for that. Sadly most of these packages are not maintained and therefore, I don't want to use them.

Comment: So why are you trying to do that? What is your goal? Why not just run it on the command line like everybody else?

Comment: Because the project is part of a monorepo that only supports JS/Ts and in order to run maven, I need some sort of wrapper. Bazel is currently not an option.

Comment: I got what you mean now. Thanks, probably works well.